# Restore a screen session after shutdown

Tags: linux, vim, gnu-screen

Not concerned with conventional attaching and detaching, I'm talking about restoring a screen session after shutting down my system entirely.

I usually have changed to various directories depending on what projects I am working on, have a bunch of files I am editing in vim, have named my screen windows accordingly, etc. It's not much, but could save me 10-15 minutes per shutdown, and more importantly, help me stay focused on what I was working on.

This would be extremely helpful for my personal workflow. Is this possible?

OS is Debian 8.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I believe there is no real answer for this question as I searched alot and got nothing yet.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not possible to save a GNU screen session. As you can imagine, with the complexity of what gets done in a terminal session, tracking and managing that would be incredibly difficult.

What I'd suggest is setting up your screen configuration so that it starts up with your preferred window layout, applications, etc. There's a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3056/save-complete-gnu-screen-session-state) that details how to do it. `vim` *can* save sessions though - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1642641/292095) for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be hibernation because is the best option. However the gnome-session-save functionality was removed, it was buggy and the official tweak to manually re-enable this functionality does not appear to work. Other option would be to use an alternative hibernation after a shutdown with TuxOnIce which is more compatible and reliable right now than the built-in hibernation.

TuxOnIce is an alternative to the kernel's built-in hibernation technology, and is supposed to be more compatible, more reliable and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you would like KDE, but that has something called activities. These are basically desktop sessions you can save. So for example you could have several terminals open, a few documents, maybe an IDE...whatever you happen to have open.

Then before you restart, you can simply save that activity. You can create as many activities as you like. You can even have the same application open in one activity that has certain files open, and have the same app in another activity with different files (imagine different projects for example).

Hopefully I haven't misunderstood your question, but to make sure do a search for KDE activities. It can be a little hard to find the right information, so if you have trouble post back here.

Best way to learn is to simply open up a whole bunch of stuff and save that as an activity. You should be able to find how to do that easily enough. Then close everything (or modify what u have) by opening new apps, or new files in the apps. Then save that as another activity.

Now you can load each activity at will, even after restarting your PC. You can have separate widgets, different virtual screens, etc. Give it a try and you should quickly determine if its what you need.

NOTE: I dont think the gnome activities are the same, as far as I know this kind of power is only achievable via the latest KDE you get with Debian 8 Jessie.